# How to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:] open other app?

Tags: iphone, uiapplication, openurl

I followed http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html instruction to open app1(GlassButton) within app2(FontTest).

The open method of FontTest as following:

```
-(void)open {

  BOOL res = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"glassbutton://"]];

  if (res) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"glassbutton://"]];

  }

}
```

The value of "res" is "YES", but nothing happen after openURL method be called. 
The info-list of "FontTest"as following:

```
URL Schemes: glassbutton

URL identifier: com.yourcompany.glassbutton
```

I tried to open twitter and facebook apps by "twitter://" and "fb://" successfully. But I do not know why I cannot open this small app. I'm not sure whether any thing/step wrong or missing?  Need I handle `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` for FontTest, if yes, how to handle it? Could you please kindly help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Say if glassbutton is the url scheme for another app, then why are you declaring it within `FontTest`'s `info.plist`. That isn't right.

Comment: Hi Deepak,

Thank you for your remind.

Answer (score 3):

To request the launch of your app use something like this:

```
NSString *urlString= @"glassbutton://com.yourcompany.glassbutton";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Then, in the glassbutton app, you'll need to handle any special behavior within the app delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    //your app specific code here for handling the launch

    return YES;
 }
```

Note that within the app you are opening the above delegate method will only get called AFTER the following method is called:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Handle accordingly, good luck.

Comment: NSString *urlString= @"glassbutton://com.yourcompany.glassbutton";

Comment: What is glassbutton, by the way?

Comment: It was the URL scheme mentioned in the original question.  Best guess is that it was a specific reference to the app in question or the company producing it - you can define your URL scheme as desired within the relevant section of your app's info plist.