# iOS: Is it possible to call an external view controller, same like calling an external activity in Android?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, external

In Android, I can call an external activity (an activity in Android is similiar to a view controller in iOS), for example the "Add event" activity of the pre-installed calendar app from my app, have the user complete the external activity and return to my app to where he left of.

I need to give my user the feature to create an event in my app, but I would prefer, that he is presented with the default calendar app's "Add event" screen, instead of creating my own UI  for that.

Is there a similiar mechanism in iOS?

Comment: The general answer is no.  There are specific cases and/or workaround which are supported.  Specifically DBD answers your calendar question and Jatin gives an answer for the case of two applications designed to work together (or more precisely, designed to allow some limited interaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Refer to [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/UsingEventViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH2-SW4). The link provided takes you right to the section which talks about UIs Apple provides to make and edit events.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for...Do you know a good tutorial or example to get started?

Comment: Try http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch32.html it's a slightly older book, but I don't think the `EKEventKit` changed significantly in iOS 7.

Comment: Your first link help me with simple sample code, let's go on with your second link. TX, you helped me very much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to now the url schemes of external applications to open them:

here is an example:

```
NSString *urlString= @"glassbutton://com.yourcompany.glassbutton";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

[How to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:] open other app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123194/how-to-use-uiapplication-sharedapplication-openurl-open-other-app)